# print cookies from QNetworkCookie, PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, cookies, pyqt

I'm trying to store all cookies that I get from a website and than print them.
Please help me to get it to work, because I think I don't store anything, and that's the reason why I have nothing on the output.

I'm testing this code on google website, and I'm pretty sure they store cookie once you get to there page.

So I'm trying to get all available cookies and print them. here is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7


from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys, os, simplejson, signal

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)
        self.settings = QSettings()
        self.numberOfTabs = 0
        self.cookies = QNetworkCookieJar()
        self.cookies.setAllCookies([QNetworkCookie.parseCookies(c)[0] for c in self.get('cookiejar')])

    def put(self, key, value):
        self.settings.setValue(key, simplejson.dumps(value))
        self.settings.sync()

    def get(self, key):
        v = self.settings.value(key)
        return simplejson.loads(unicode(v.toString())) 

    def addNewTab(self, url=QUrl('')):
        self.numberOfTabs += 1
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(self.tabs.addTab(Tab(QUrl(url)),'%s'%str(self.numberOfTabs)))
        self.setCookies()
        return self.tabs.currentWidget()

    def setCookies(self):
        self.put('cookiejar', [str(c.toRawForm()) for c in self.cookies.allCookies()])
        print self.get('cookiejar')

class Tab(QWebView):
    def __init__(self, url):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.load(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = MainWindow()
    browser.addNewTab('https://google.com')
    browser.show()
    if signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably wait for `loadFinished` before checking for cookies, anyway, maybe something like this works for you, here I reimplement `QNetworkCookieJar` and do all the work of storing and loading cookies from there:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 2)
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit, QtNetwork

class cookieJar(QtNetwork.QNetworkCookieJar):
    def __init__(self, cookiesKey, parent=None):
        super(cookieJar, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mainWindow = parent
        self.cookiesKey = cookiesKey
        cookiesValue    = self.mainWindow.settings.value(self.cookiesKey)       

        if cookiesValue:
            cookiesList = QtNetwork.QNetworkCookie.parseCookies(cookiesValue)
            self.setAllCookies(cookiesList)

    def setCookiesFromUrl (self, cookieList, url):
        cookiesValue = self.mainWindow.settings.value(self.cookiesKey)
        cookiesArray = cookiesValue if cookiesValue else QtCore.QByteArray()

        for cookie in cookieList:
            cookiesArray.append(cookie.toRawForm() + "\n")

        self.mainWindow.settings.setValue(self.cookiesKey, cookiesArray)

        return super(cookieJar, self).setCookiesFromUrl(cookieList, url)

class webView(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    def __init__(self, cookiesKey, url, parent=None):
        super(webView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.cookieJar = cookieJar(cookiesKey, parent)

        self.page().networkAccessManager().setCookieJar(self.cookieJar)

class myWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.cookiesKey = "cookies"

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setTabsClosable(True)

        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.actionTabAdd = QtGui.QAction(self)
        self.actionTabAdd.setText("Add Tab")
        self.actionTabAdd.triggered.connect(self.on_actionTabAdd_triggered)

        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setText("http://www.example.com")

        self.toolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(self)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionTabAdd)
        self.toolBar.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.ToolBarArea(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea), self.toolBar)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.settings = QtCore.QSettings()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionShowCookies_triggered(self):
        webView = self.tabWidget.currentWidget()
        listCookies = webView.page().networkAccessManager().cookieJar().allCookies()

        for cookie in  listCookies:
            print cookie.toRawForm()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_actionTabAdd_triggered(self):
        url = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.addNewTab(url if url else 'about:blank')

    def addNewTab(self, url):
        tabName = u"Tab {0}".format(str(self.tabWidget.count()))

        tabWidget= webView(self.cookiesKey, url, self)
        tabWidget.loadFinished.connect(self.on_tabWidget_loadFinished)
        tabWidget.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))

        tabIndex = self.tabWidget.addTab(tabWidget, tabName)

        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(tabIndex)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_tabWidget_loadFinished(self):
        print self.settings.value(self.cookiesKey)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myWindow')

    main = myWindow()
    main.resize(666, 333)
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```